# Is there a WPF progressbar like the Windows Phone dots?

Tags: wpf, animation, progress-bar

The subject really says it all:

Is there a WPF progressbar like the Windows Phone dots?

Comment: Got any screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: ControlTemplate, yeah? [This should help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334413%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there's not an easy answer, but I found one here:
http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you template the current one. this is how you could template one:
http://www.mobydisk.com/softdev/techinfo/flaming_progress_bar/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to get something like in the picture this there is a solution.

[get MahApps.Metro from nuget](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)

And use the following code

```xml
 <Window x:Class="Client.Login"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="650" Width="450" >
        <Controls:MetroProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True"/>
 </Window>
```